# How can I parse information returned from the Twitter Search API?

Tags: c#, twitter

I am currently building a web application that interacts with the Twitter Search API and returns tweets based on input. I am getting data returned to me, but it is coming in such a way that I do not know what to do with it. Can somebody suggest an improvement or how I can handle this data so I can format the results?

Here is the code:

```
    public ActionResult SearchTwitter(string authenticationCode, TwitterSearch twitterSearch) //TwitterSearch holds information needed to build the URL
    {
        string url = BuildURL(twitterSearch);
        var gettimeline = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        gettimeline.Method = "GET";
        gettimeline.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        gettimeline.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + authenticationCode;
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        try
        {
            var respbody = ""; //used to be string
            using (var resp = gettimeline.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())//there request sends
            {
                var respR = new StreamReader(resp);
                respbody = respR.ReadToEnd();
            }

            result = Json(respbody);
        }
```

This is the trouble spot, everything else is fine (such as the catch and return statement at the end).

I am not sure where to go to effectively parse this data, as the JsonResult.Data object is a string, which isn't helpful in this situation.

Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Where is the code to parse???  There are oodles and oodles of posts here on parsing and deserializing JSON

Comment: @Plutonix I don't have that yet since I am confused as to why it is coming back as a straight up string. Is it supposed to do that?

Comment: Yes - do some simple research like what JSON stands for: Javascript Serialized Object Notation.  It is the text representation of an object - after being sent somewhere the receiver can recreate the original object - or parse out the bits they are interested in.  If I google your title I get 1.8 million hits with many many many on this site alone  Reading [ask] and taking the [tour] at this point would not be a bad idea either

Comment: Thanks - I am getting nervous as my deadline in Friday, so I am probably being overly hasty. I will take the time to figure out the best way to parse the information being sent back.

Sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParsingLINQtoJSON.htm), like this:

```
        var respbody = ""; //used to be string
        using (var resp = gettimeline.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())//there request sends
        {
            var respR = new StreamReader(resp);
            respbody = respR.ReadToEnd();
            JObject timeline = JObject.Parse(respbody);
            // use the docs at Newtonsoft.com to figure out how to read timeline
        }
```

Notice that I added `JObject.Parse(respbody)`, which gives you a `JObject` containing the parsed JSON data. The documentation at Newtonsoft.com is pretty decent and shouldn't take much time to work through to figure out the rest.

You can install the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/11.0.1-beta3) package from NuGet. Alternatively, you might also consider a 3rd party library, like [LINQ to Twitter](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter) (which I wrote), to make this even easier.